# is if(float > int) really if(float > (float)int)?

Tags: c#, casting, floating-point, comparison, int

is

```
 if(float > int)
```

really just

```
 if(float > (float)int)
```

I was doing so research and it seems like it costs a lot to do float to int and int to float casts. 
I have a lot of float/int comparisons.

Just a quick question

Answer (score 6):

## Yes!

### They're the same thing.

There's **no instruction** to directly compare a floating-point to an integer, so it first casts the integer to `float`.

---

#### However:

Be careful: That does **not** mean that the `int`-to-`float` conversion is lossless. It still can lose some information, so this code:

```
(int)(float)integer == integer
```

doesn't always evaluate to `true`! (Try it with `int.MaxValue` to see. Ditto with `double`/`long`.)

Comment: It's worth noting that while `1000000001 > (float)1000000000` wo;; return false, that's because the latter quantity doesn't really represent "1,000,000,000".  Instead, it represents "something between 999,999,968 and 1,000,000,032"; the former quantity is not definitively larger than the latter.  Note that 1222333443 will compare equal to 1222333444f, but 1222333443.0 will compare greater than 1222333444f, since the latter will get coerced into 1222333440.0 (conversions between float and double regard conversion from less specific to more specific as "widening"--the opposite of other types).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There's no `>(float, int)` operator - just >(int, int) and `>(float, float)`. So the compiler calls the latter operator by converting the second operand to `float`. See section 7.3.6.2 of the C# spec for more details:

> Binary numeric promotion occurs for the operands of the predefined +, -, *, / %, &, |, ^, ==, !=, >, <, >= and <= binary operators. Binary numeric promotion implicitly converts both operands to a common type which, in case of the nonrelational operators, also becomes the result type of the operation.

(It then lists the steps involved.)

Are you sure that the `int` to `float` conversion is taking a lot of time though? It should be pretty cheap.